# Is there anyone out there who regularly marks essays etc?

Tags: discussion

I have yet to meet any contributor to the site who regularly marks undergraduate essays, in one of the humanities fields. That kind of person would surely be able to supply useful information as to what is accepted, and what is not, as 'correct' English grammar. after all one definition of 'correctness', in our variegated search for it, must be 'that which is accepted by examiners and others in universities etc'. Whilst the OED is a help, so much of it is archaic.

Comment: The point has been made many times here that there is no single authority who can pronounce on what is or isn't "correct" English. For all I know, there could be dozens of ELU members who mark undergraduate essays. But even if there were, it's highly unlikely they'd all agree on exactly what's correct/acceptable in all situations. Also, it's ridiculous to suggest OED is "archaic". The online edition is bang-up-to-date (I read today that they've recently included "omnishambles", for example)

Comment: The 'one definition' you refer to would certainly be accepted by examiners and others in humanities departments, but probably not many others.

Comment: There very well may be people on ELU who do regularly mark essays even at the undergrad level (actually I suspect not many; they're probably too tired of their daily work to come here to do more unpaid). And there certainly is a correct version or standard of English to hold people to (actually more than one standard, and then how people speak vs, write, and different levels of formality, etc.). And ELU answerers tend to the latter multitude of standards. What was the question again? Do you want us to proofread your work?

Comment: [ell.se] being a site specifically chartered for the use of students and teachers of the English language, you might find what you are looking for there.

Comment: I think that everyone here has more or less missed the point, which perhaps reflects badly on my ability to ask the question. But imagine yourselves as a history lecturer marking undergraduate essays. One of the things on your check list of points to look for, together with such things as 'grasp of the issues', and 'evidence of wide reading', will be 'standard of written English'. Within the last category you will have 'creative writing ability' and 'grammar'. It is the last one which I think provides a valuable pointer. (Cont'd)

Comment: I know all the arguments about there being no hard and fast rules and as I have said before I began life among people who might converse in sentences which contained the word 'do' six times. That would NOT be acceptable in a university. So what is? You cannot go on ducking the question. There is a dividing line between the acceptable and the unacceptable. That, in my view is what needs to be addressed.

Comment: There is no "ducking" going on here. Not everything in English falls into the two neat categories of "correct" and "incorrect". There are colloquialisms, vernaculars, slang, jargon, informal expressions, awkward constructs, and so forth. Much of what Mark Twain wrote (particularly between the quotation marks) makes for horrible English, yet his books are well-used in English classes. Back to your question. If you are looking for "grammar" as part of your grading criteria, one fairly easy error to find is subject-verb agreement, but beware – that's not the only way to write a horrible sentence.

Comment: In those terms what we need to be clear about is which words,  in a serious essay, need to go between quotation marks. Mark Twain is not alone, you could say the same of Shakespeare, I feel sure. But that is not the point. There is a standard of English which is expected in university essays or in an editorial in the Guardian or the New York Times. Two nights ago I saw the editor of the NYT interviewed on BBC's Newsnight about the Edward Snowdon affair. She is clearly a highly erudite woman, and she wouldn't stand for rubbish English from her staff. Of that I feel certain.

Comment: Perhaps an analogy will help. You were an accountant: were you never frustrated by columnists and clients who spoke glibly about "good" investments without carefully analyzing risks? who sneered at this or that rate of return as "shabby" without regard to objectives? In these parts we feel the same frustration with people who speak glibly about "correct" and "rubbish" English, without regard to audience and purpose.

Comment: @stoneyB Absolutely. Don't think I always use perfectly syntaxed grammar when I speak to my wife and children. And in business it can sometimes help to speak with the voice of a working man. I cherish the regional dialects of Britain as much as the very landscape. I also enjoy listening to New Yorkers and Southerners.  And I lived in Australia for a time where I soon converted much of my speech to Australian. Notwithstanding this I still argue that children should be taught grammatical English. It doesn't mean they ought not to perform in plays which involve the use of incorrect English.

Comment: But 'grammatical English' is English which observes the rules and practices of the speech community to which it is addressed. 'Correctness' is a matter of context, not of adherence to an arbitrary 'standard'. In East Anglia you speak one dialect, in East Alabama we speak another, in Academe we both speak and write a wide variety of distinct dialects (English professors mostly find the dialect written by Sociology professors repulsive). Each is 'correct' in its own context and 'incorrect' out of it.

Comment: I just can't imagine what life would be like if children in Liverpool were taught a form of grammar entirely different to those in Bristol or London. It was the Victorians who brought in a standard pronunciation for the educated classes which is what we call RP (Received Pronunciation) When the BBC got going in the 1920s it was predicted that it would be the death knell of regional dialects, since the BBC would use RP, which they do. In fact it is often described as BBC English. Yet oddly after nearly a century the British regional dialects are as vibrant as ever. (Cont'd)

Comment: No one quite knows why they survive but they do, perhaps more than in any western country. A young friend who is a Russian graduate and lives and works in Moscow tell us that regional dialect variations in Russia are not nearly as strong as the UK. Given the size of Russia that is surprising. But having a separate grammar for every region would be unthinkable. Someone from Newcastle going to University in London would effectively have to learn a new language. From my experience of America regional variations are far less common than in Britain and the same arguments must surely apply.

Comment: Our regional dialects have largely been leveled, because we've been leveling them much longer. But we share the fundamental dialectal divide between the spoken and written languages. And on both sides of the Atlantic we obscure the enormous diversity of written dialects by calling them 'styles'.

Comment: ... and I think English professors over here would tell you that most college freshmen, wherever they come from, have been so little exposed to the written language that they **are** effectively having to learn a new language.

Comment: Some of the very recent reports on children's literacy in Britain have also made for depressing reading. The sad fact is that teenagers are now spending so much time glued to their screens and their phones, typing 140 character messages in predictive script, that they have never experienced what it is to read a book. I am not sure anyone has any clear idea of where technology is taking us, but I rather fear it is not to a good place.

Comment: WS2: Is the word "bullshit" grammatical? Acceptable? Erudite? I would say: If overused, it can sound rather juvenile; if used in formal company, it can sound coarse and vulgar. But there may be a situation where it's the right word at the right time in the right place for the right audience. So, back to your issue: college essays. If "proper grammar" is a grading criterion for a college essay, and a student used the word _bullshit_ – even outside the quotation marks – would you dock a point or two? The answer is that dreaded answer: "It depends" (which is to say, "There is no easy answer").

Comment: @JR If someone were writing an essay on the 1848 revolutions across Europe, I would not expect to find the word 'bullshit'. In the extremely unlikely event someone found a reason to do so e.g. 'At the time of the famine one Irish peasant was executed for having said "bullshit" to his landlord' (if it were true) then that would be fine. But if the writer simply said, as part of his own narrative 'Metternich thought the Italians were given to talking bullshit', then he would be marked down for lack of ability to write English properly. (Cont'd)

Comment: @JR Move from history to a sociological essay on street graffiti. I would expect it to be peppered with words like 'bullshit' because that is what street graffiti is about. Is that reasonably clear?

Comment: @JR If that differs in any way from what would happen in a US Ivy League university I would be very surprised.

Comment: WS2: Yes, my point exactly – it's context dependent. Moreover, the point I've made concerning a single word would be equally murky with so-called grammatical rules, like ending a sentence with a preposition, or starting a sentence with a conjuction. Fragments, too. But I digress. Point is, you'll have a hard time putting together some list of rules that will reliably tell you when to deduct a point for a grammatical faux pas, because such breaches are not always a sign of weak writing.

Comment: @J.R. It is not done in quite the punctilious way you suggest. But if an essay contains repeated spelling mistakes or errors of grammar, the student will lose marks. You will also be given added credit for especially creative or elegant writing. Above all, literacy is about entertainment and if you entertain your reader well you will be appreciated, no matter where you are writing.

Comment: WS2: So, what's your question here again?

Comment: @J.R. Exactly as expressed in my OP. There must be some rule of thumb which academics employ in determining what amounts to good English and bad English. If I were in the habit of inventing new words such as I have seen liberally around this site such as 'distinctification', 'transitivizing' etc. I think this would cause puckered brows in any UK arts stream.  A sentence such as 'the Austrian foreign policy was followed through with' would be seen as distinctly ugly. The point is you would not get those crucial few marks added at the end for having written elegant English.

Comment: @J.R. I mean these ridiculously long words that people create (bourgeoisification is one I have seen, and all those words ending in*ization etc ) are simply down to the laziness of not being bothered to think of a more literate way of speaking or writing.

Comment: That sounds like a rant, not a question. Where did you see [_distinctification_](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=distinctification)? As for [_transitivizing_](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=transitivizing), almost every instance of that was written by @JohnLawler, a retired grammar professor. Frankly, I learn a lot from him. He is a specialist writing to enthusiasts, so the occasional technical term doesn't come off as haughty in that context. As for "there must be some rule of thumb .. in determining what amounts to good English and bad English," good luck with that one.

Comment: @J.R. Are you honestly saying that you cannot look at a piece of writing and say 'that's well written' or 'that's badly written'? An experienced football watcher will tell you after half an hour who is having a good game and who is not. In the same way someone who marks essays knows after they have read the opening paragraph whether the person can write decent English or not. What I am asking is 'What are the tell-tale signs which indicate a literate mind'.

Comment: Sure, I can tell, usually no later than Page 2. But to explain it with "some rule of thumb" – that's a hefty challenge. "What are the tell-tale signs indicating a literate mind" is a more reasonable request, but it took you 2 days and 14 comments to finally ask for that. Your original question merely asked about "a kind of person [who] would surely be able to supply useful information as to what is accepted, and what is not, as 'correct' English grammar." A football fan can tell good from bad, but try asking for a "rule of thumb" to differentiate between bad offense and stellar defense.

Comment: @J.R. Ability to control the ball with a single touch, ability to turn both to right and left with equal ease to get away from an opponent, ability to kick with both feet, awareness of the location of team mates, a positional understanding including critically how much space to leave between you and your fellow defenders, speed, a calm temperament.... How many more do you want?

Comment: @J.R. I am happy to settle for a draw (tie) with you on this one. Clearly all things of this kind, whether it be in sport or language, can ultimately be broken down to 'rules of thumb'. Certain features of good English/bad English can easily be described. I was simply seeking examples from people who had to make that judgement daily. But you are right in the sense that the debate has been necessary to crystallise my argument. So one point to you and one to me.

Comment: You didn't initially ask for "rules of thumb," you asked for "some rule of thumb." Singular. That's where I wished you luck. Now you're asking for a set. That's a different question, and it's probably too broadly scoped for a forum such as this one. Keep score however you'd like, but I haven't conceded any point yet.

Comment: @J.R. In my OP, if you would care to look, I never mentioned 'rule of thumb' in either the singular or the plural. I simply suggested such a person might be able to supply 'useful information as to what is accepted and what is not, as (being) correct'. That, I submit, was an appeal for the very generalised views of an expert who examines students scripts day in day out as to what might be described as good English. So far no such academics have presented themselves.

Comment: I've looked at both your original post, and your comments, several times. When I said, "Good luck with that," I was responding to your _comment_, where you said, "there must be some rule of thumb .. in determining what amounts to good English and bad English." Those are your words; I assumed you were trying to clarify what you were after. You responded by asking me, "Are you honestly saying..." blah blah blah. If I was answering your OP, I would leave an answer below; instead we're going round in circles. Why would someone here invest a lot of time satisfying your silly request? Go buy a book.

Comment: You might try [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Real-Writing-Readings-Paragraphs-Everyday/dp/0312539045/ref=pd_sim_b_1) for starters. Or maybe [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Writing-Style-Conversations-Art-3rd/dp/0205028802/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1382136904&sr=1-1).

Comment: From another of your comments: "There is a dividing line between the acceptable and the unacceptable. That .. is what needs to be addressed." There you go with the singular again. There is no one dividing line, there are many, many dividing lines, each of which can be applied one sentence (or one paragraph) at a time. As when you answered my football question, "There's W, X, Y, Z, A, B, C.... How many more do you want?" The answer to your request would be the same thing: use proper capitalization, avoid run-on sentences, employ meaty paragraphs.... How many more do you want?

Comment: If you really want to help your undergraduate students, instead of giving them yet another list of grammatical and rhetorical DOs and DON'Ts, exhort them to proofread, revise, and edit. The key to good writing is rewriting. The quality of term papers could be greatly improved if students would simply learn to (a) recognize their own bad writing, and (b) get out of the habit of writing papers the night before they're due and turning in what is effectively a first draft. But that's probably a question better addressed at [academia.SE] than at ELU.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the quest for a single person to dictate the *rules* is misguided.  Instead, I believe it will be more practical for you to study the concept of prescriptivism vs descriptivism.

Before I began participating on this site, I had no awareness that such a distinction existed.  None of my totalitarian English teachers had ever let slip that rules are not universal truths.  They simply meted out what is right and what is wrong, and woe unto the student who dared to defend his "improper" grammar.

The reality is, what is "correct" is sometimes debated between prescriptivists, and often subject to change.  What is "correct" today may not be the standard at some time in the very near future.  One good example of this is ["the death of "whom."](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html)  It is widely believed by descriptivists that the rule for usage of who vs whom is on its deathbed (and I tend to agree.)

**I don't want to bog down this answer with too many words, because I would really like to have you read [this blog post.](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/prescriptivism-and-descriptivism/)   I sincerely believe that it will be helpful to you.**

Comment: I have certainly never advocated, nor can I imagine anyone in their right mind would, that we should seek a 'single person to dictate the rules'. Language is a bit like the law. No one person says what the law should be, and often (certainly in English-speaking jurisdictions) it doesn't only come from legislators. There is a huge body of case law. Often lawyers do not know what the law is until they research it. Law is made on the hoof by judges. Whilst some things are clearly outside the law, some English should not appear in serious print, except between quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

I daresay there are several of us.

I myself have been out of the education racket for decades; but from the age of 12 until I left for college, I regularly marked undergraduate English papers for my father (it was his way of teaching me what he called 'practical grammar'), and I taught university-level theatre history and criticism for some years in the 1970s.

The canons here prohibit proofreading; but if you stand in need of it, I will be happy to point out—or, if you prefer, to correct, silently—any deficiencies of language and argument I notice in your posts.